# Re-executing statements in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

Sorry for the noobie question but I need some help in figuring out how to return execution back to the start of a subroutine after a logical block is done checking user input.

```
Program FibSequence 
Integer(2) :: n_terms
print*, "Please Enter number 0-99"
read*,n_terms
call check_term()
End Program
```

```
Subroutine check_term()

if n_terms <= 0 then 
!print stuff
read*, n_terms
return
else if n_terms > 99 then
!print stuff
read*, n_terms
return
else
print*, "you have chosen " , n_terms
end
```

The program executes successfully but it does not do what it should do.

I am suspecting the program enters the check then when it does that if the number is incorrectly chosen such that the number is > 99 or <= 0 then it "rereads" the n_terms for user input then returns the execution to the main program which results in the program terminating.

The result should be when the number is incorrectly chosen the sub routine is ran entirely AGAIN instead of going to the next line of execution from main - which would be end program.

Help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect it to run again? You've done nothing to make it run again. You need to call it in a loop and you need `check_term()` to indicate success or failure so you know when to exit the loop.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thats a good observation, my apologies for the noobie question lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use an alternate return, but alternate return is in the list of obsolescent features. Perhaps, the easiest way to achieve what you want to do is with an infinite `DO` loop that exits on valid input.

```
Program FibSequence 
  Integer(2) :: n_terms   ! Note, non-portable kind type parameter
  print*, "Please Enter number 0-99"
  do
     read*,n_terms
     if (n_terms > -1 .and. n_terms < 100) exit
  end do
  ! Do something with n_terms.
End Program
```

Comment: Elegant and precise, if I would like to keep the subroutine should I nest the check within the subroutine or have it exist in the main() of the program?

Comment: Sure, you can move the `DO` loop into the subroutine.  Do note that the prompt is only printed once.

Comment: Cool, is ```GOTO```  outdated as well ?

Comment: No. `GOTO` is still a part of the language.  Some here in SO frown on its use because  they heard that someone once wrote a paper claiming `GOTO` was bad.

Comment: Yes, `goto` is outdated :-)  There are very few cases where it is the best statement to use, and many many cases where it tends towards code that is difficult for a human to follow.